Mathematics for Machine Learning by Marc Peter Deisenroth, A. Aldo Faisal, and Cheng Soon Ong. Theorem 2.20 (basis change) questions
I am struggling to understand this proof, and have some questions which I will list. Here is a link to the textbook
https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf
and the theorem and proof I am referencing is on page 54. I will ask questions under the assumption that those answering have read and understood the proof.
Please note that I did not work out how to use tilde here, so I am using * instead.
Question 1.
It says that we define $\textbf{S}$ as the transformation matrix that maps coords with respect to B* onto coordinates with respect to B. However, in equation 2.106, is the sum not demonstrating how $\textbf{S} = ((s_{ij}))$ is being used to map B to B*?
Question 2.
Equation 2.108. I am confused why the mapping $\Phi$ is being applied to $b*_j$, I thought $\Phi$ was for the original bases. Why is this the approach?
Question 3. Equation 2.108. Why is it valid to swap the order of summation, as well as the order of $t_{lk}$ and $a*_{kj}$?
If there is another proof of this formula that may explain things differently, I would like to see.
Thanks in advance.

Are you aware that if $v\in V$ and there is a basis change $S$ in, then the new components of $v$ are got by multiplying $[S]^{-1}[v]$ ? in the column matrix $[v]$ are the old components of vector $v$.

Question 1: If we have a coordinate vector with respect to $B^*$, let's call it $v=(v_1, \dots, v_n)$, then this corresponds to the vector $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i b_i^*$. With respect to $B$ we can write this (using equation (2.106)) as
$$\sum_{i=1}^n v_ib_i^*=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i \sum_{k=1}^n s_{ki}b_k= \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n s_{ki}v_i b_k = \sum_{k=1}^n (Sv)_k b_k$$
which shows that the vector $Sv$ is the coordinate vector with respect to $B$. In that sense, $S$ maps coordinates w.r.t. $B^*$ to coordinates with respect to $B$.
Question 2: The original linear mapping $\Phi$ is defined for every vector in the vector space $V$. It has nothing to do with bases. Only the representing matrices are with respect to a fixed basis, the original mapping doesn't know about bases.
Question 3: Since we are summing up finitely many terms, the commutative law allows to change the order of summation. The same holds for changing the order ot $t_{lk}$ and $a^*_{kj}$. These are just numbers in a field (probably real or complex numbers) for which the commutative law of multiplication holds.

Thanks for answering my questions, I am satisfied with Q2 and Q3 but still unsure of Q1.
If we have an ordered basis $B = (b_1, ..., b_n)$, we can represent a vector $x = \alpha_1b_1, ..., \alpha_nb_n$, and the vector $\alpha$ is the coordinate representation with respect to $B$. In the equation above, as I understand you replaced $b^{}{i}$ with $s{ki}b_{k}$, and the columns of $\textbf{S}$ are the coord rep of $b^{}$ w.r.t to $B$, so how is it that $\textbf{S}$ is the transformation matrix that maps coords w.r.t to $B^{*}$ onto coords w.r.t $B$ and not the other way around?

The equation I have in my answer shows the following: The vector $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i b_i^$ is the same as the vector $\sum_{i=1}^n (Sv)_i b_i$ where $(Sv)_i$ denotes the $i$-th component of the vector $Sv$. This means: if I want to describe the same vector w.r.t. to the basis $B^$ and the basis $B$ I have to apply the matrix $S$ to the coordinate vector $v$ to get from coordinates w.r.t. $B^*$ to the coordinates w.r.t. $B$.

So, just to be clear, S can be applied to a coordinate vector w.r.t to $B^{}$ to get a vector w.r.t $B$, and it is also true that $B^{}$ is a linear combination of the columns of S and $B$?

Yes, both are true. Concering the second point: A vector $b_j^$ in $B^$ is a linear combination of vectors in $B$ with weights being the numbers in the $j$-th column of $S$.

Use a components free formulation:
Let $S$ be a basis change in $V$. If $T$ is the basis change in $W$ then, for a vector $v$ when transformed, we obtain the new components with
$T^{-1}(\Phi(v))$.
But if we introduce the basis change $S$ into that
we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
T^{-1}(\Phi(v))&=&T^{-1}\Phi(SS^{-1}(v)),\\
&=&(T^{-1}\Phi S)\ S^{-1}(v).
\end{eqnarray*}
Here, we see how the new components of $\Phi(v)$ are related with the new components of $v$.
The matrix that do the work is that of  $\ T^{-1}\Phi S$.
